# Setting the Java heap size in Launch4j does not work properly

Tags: java, memory, launch4j

When setting the heap size for a program that needs, say, around 3 GB, you could just set the maximum heap size by adding `-Xmx8g` to the command line for 8 gigabytes in that case. That actually works fine with *JAR*s in case of my program.

Now, I try to create an *EXE* file by using *Launch4j*, and I have set the 'initial heap size' and 'max heap size' options to values of 8000 MB.

However, this does not give me the same result I got when doing it the way I described above (with the *JAR*s). At a certain point of around 1000 MB (when running my program), it just stops and no longer allocates more memory.

When filling nothing into the 'heap size' options in *Launch4j*, the limit is equal to the one that results from **not** adding the `-Xmx8g` option to the command line when running the *JAR* file (both stop at only around 300 MB). That means that setting the heap sizes in *Launch4j* actually does something, but does not make the heap as big as it should be.

Why do the *Launch4j* heap size options not work properly and is it somehow possible for it to actually work?

Comment: Did the parameters -Xms and -Xmx get added to your program?

Comment: What do you mean by 'get added to my program'? When starting the *JAR* file, I added those parameters to the command line.
When it comes to *Launch4j*, I just set the parameters using the UI.

Comment: What I meant was when you ran your program, do those arguments show up in the VM arguments for the corresponding java pid?

Comment: Thanks for your help, the arguments were all fine; I now found out that the problem was that I was using a 32 bit JRE instead of a 64 bit one and set the *Launch4j* bundled path to this 32 bit one. That lead to the small amount of memory.